# Writing unicode type objects to file in Python

Tags: python, unicode, mojibake

I'm trying to write unicode strings to a file in Python but when I read the file using linux "cat" or "less" the correct characters are not written, instead they show up as garbage.

I am reading the object from an Oracle database.  When I print the type (where a is a row in the database results):

```
logger.debug(type(a[index]))
```

it outputs:

```
<type 'unicode'>
```

I open the file for writing like so:

```
ff = codecs.open(filename, mode='w', encoding='utf-8')
```

and I write the line to the file like:

```
ff.write(a[index]))
```

but when I read the output file, it doesn't show the correctly accented characters but garbage instead:

```
$Buï¿½ï¿½rger, Udo, -1985. Way to perfect horsemanship
```

How do I correctly write unicode string objects to a file in Python?

Comment: How are you reading the file?  Does whatever software you're using to read it know that it should be reading it as UTF-8?  What is the encoding of your linux terminal?

Comment: What does `logger.debug(repr(a[index]))` write? You appear to have a mighty big [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) there.

Comment: If I encode that text to Latin-1 then decode again as UTF-8 I get `u'$Bu\ufffd\ufffdrger, Udo, -1985. Way to perfect horsemanship\n'`. Not quite legible but does indicate you used `error='replace'` here when you decoded something with the *wrong* encoding. U+FFFD is the default replacement character when you use that error handling.

Comment: Sounds like `a[index]` contains two instances of the unicode replacement character (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm), which is getting correctly encoded as utf-8. However, your terminal is reading using latin-1 instead of utf-8. The terminal problem should be easy to fix, figuring out why you have replacement characters I would expect to be harder. Unless that's what you expect to be there, I guess.

Comment: echo $LANG reports en_US.UTF-8.  I only used the terminal output as an example though.  The problem still shows up when I subsequently open and read the file using `file = codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')` and `file.readline()`.  I output what's returned from readline using Django's render_to_response and in the html output garbage shows up.

Comment: Can you show us the `repr()` of the data as you write it to the file? You'll have to do this at various points in your code, really; where you receive the data from Oracle for example. By the time you are writing it to the file it is almost certainly corrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can *guess* at how you arrived at that [Mojibake of a string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). It is quite involved, I am impressed how mucked up this got to be.

Something decoded text from bytes to Unicode with `error='replace'`, masking the fact the wrong codec was used as as bytes that weren't recognized were replaced with replacement characters.

The resulting Unicode text with [U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](http://codepoints.net/U+FFFD) codepoints was then encoded to UTF-8, but decoded them again as Latin 1, most likely by your terminal as `cat` or `les` output the raw bytes.

The text encoded this way is:

```
>>> print u'$Buï¿½ï¿½rger, Udo, -1985. Way to perfect horsemanship'.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
$Bu��rger, Udo, -1985. Way to perfect horsemanship
```

Presumably this was meant to be *Bürger, Udo, - 1985. Way to perfect horsemanship*, with the `ü` being formed by the character `u` and the [U+0308 COMBINING DIAERESIS](http://codepoints.net/U+0308) codepoint, which would have been CC 88 in UTF-8, but not decodable as ASCII:

```
>>> text = u'Bu\u0308rger, Udo, - 1985. Way to perfect horsemanship'
>>> print text
Bürger, Udo, - 1985. Way to perfect horsemanship
>>> text.encode('utf8')
'Bu\xcc\x88rger, Udo, - 1985. Way to perfect horsemanship'
>>> text.encode('utf8').decode('ascii', errors='replace')
u'Bu\ufffd\ufffdrger, Udo, - 1985. Way to perfect horsemanship'
```

The moral of the story: **Don't use `errors='replace'` unless you are absolutely sure what you are doing**.

Comment: Hi Martijn, thanks for the response. This is what repr outputs just after I receive the data from Oracle (before I operate on it at all): `u'Bu\ufffd\ufffdrger, Udo, -1985....'`. I haven't used `errors='replace'` anywhere in my code. And I'm pretty sure when I saw the DBA run the query while using the Oracle client it displayed correctly so it is in the database correctly. I am using the cx_Oracle driver and Django's raw sql methods to query the database. I am wondering if cx_Oracle or Django is responsible for mucking it up somehow and inserting the U+FFFD replacement character. Thanks.

Comment: Right. What are the versions of Django, Oracle, the Oracle Client libraries, and cx_Oracle? What, if anything, is the NLS_LANG environment variable set to? If you import `cx_Oracle` into a python session, does `cx_Oracle.UNICODE` exist?

Comment: Django is 1.6.4 and cx_Oracle is 5.1.2. Our DBA reports that Instant Client is 11.2.0.4 and Oracle on the server is 10.2.0.4 and that NLS_LANG is set to AMERICAN.AMERICA.US7ASCII.  When I import cx_Oracle, yes, cx_Oracle.UNICODE exists.  So is the problem that NLS_LANG is not set to American_America.UTF8 on the server and client?  Thanks.

Comment: @user45183: Yes, the problem is `NLS_LANG` here; set it to something matching the UTF-8 data in the database.

Comment: @user45183: Note that on the client side, [Django already sets `NLS_LANG` to `'.UTF8'`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py#L34) to force the issue.